# Getting error syntax error: 'if' unmatched while executing bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I wanted to create a bash script to achieve a particular task although i have no knowledge of bash.
Lazily asking it here directly wouldn't have have explained my question well , so i just kept struggling for 1 hour and got as far as i could so that there's atleast a basic structure of my code ( even tho possibly broken but still it would easier to get my question so more people will be willing to help ).

First lemme show exactly the error which i am getting

```
$ su
$ sh "/sdcard/tester.sh"
/sdcard/tester.sh[2]: syntax error: 'if' unmatched
```

Code below

```
#!/bin/bash
PACKAGE='com.mixplorer'
if [ $(pidof $PACKAGE) ]; then
am force-stop com.mixplorer
am start -n com.mixplorer/.activities.BrowseActivity

loopcleaner()
{
rm -rf /sdcard/log.txt
}

while [ $(pidof $PACKAGE) ]
do
loopcleaner
sleep 10

if [ ! $(pidof $PACKAGE) ]; then
break
mkdir /sdcard/successful.txt
fi
done
```

Explanation of what i am trying to achieve:

1) As soon as script is executed , first check if file manager with package name 'com.mixplorer' process is already active 
If yes , then force stop it and open it again
If no , then just simply open it

2) Now that the file manager is already opened , keep deleting a file named 'log.txt' as defined by loopcleaner every 10 seconds in a loop forever as long as file manager process is running

3) Only after file manager process is no longer active , end the loop cleaning process from step 2 and create a file named successful.txt .
After creating this file , script should end / kill its own process

Comment: missing `fi` for the first `if`

Comment: @glennjackman Yes thanks that did it

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Answer (score 1):

Add `fi` at the end of this section, like this:

```
if [ $(pidof $PACKAGE) ]; then
am force-stop com.mixplorer
am start -n com.mixplorer/.activities.BrowseActivity
fi
```

Comment: Yes that fixed it.  Although i can't trust myself that i have done everything else mentioned in my three statements correctly , can you confirm it once please

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: everything is working well now except that successful.txt is not getting created .i will try fine tuning it. Maybe i need to keep it like - if file manager is removed from recents , force stop it. Then create that successful. Txt file ... In any case marking your answer as accepted. I will ask a new one later for another purpose if i have to seek some help

Comment: I'm an idiot! Use `touch /sdcard/successful.txt` instead of `mkdir`.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Also, you can't expect to run `touch` or `mkdir` just after `break`.

Comment: @Kusalananda - you're right, the `break` should come after the `touch`.